# Get a undefined return value, although in function it wasn't

Tags: javascript

```
function getCheckedRadioButton() {
    getRadioButtons().forEach(function (t) {
        if (t.checked) {
            console.log(t);
            return t;
        }
    });
}
```

The function above get called in:

```
var x = getCheckedRadioButton();
console.log(x);
if (x.className)
{
    //do something
}
```

Console output:

```
input type="radio" id="pvp" name="gameMode" value="0" class="hasTextboxes"
undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
```

I even tried:

```
if (getCheckedRadioButton().className)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: How does the function getRadioButtons looks like?

Comment: That `return t;` is inside the *callback* function. It won't return from the outer function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
return t;
```

Is returning from this function:

```
function (t) {
  //...
}
```

*Not* this one:

```
getCheckedRadioButton() {
  //...
}
```

What exactly are you trying to return?  Just the first matching result in the array?  You could just use a normal loop instead of one with a nested function:

```
var radios = getRadioButtons();
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        console.log(radios[i]);
        return radios[i];
    }
}
// return some default if nothing is found?
```

Comment: Or use `Array.prototype.find`.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning from the callback (anonymous function) of `forEach` not from the function `getCheckedRadioButton`. The function `getCheckedRadioButton` doesn't return anything so its return value is `undefined`.

If you want to reurn the first checked radio button use `find`. `find` will return the first item from the array that its callback call returned `true` (the item that has `t.checked` set to `true`) or `null` if no item is matched. Then we should return that item/`null` to the caller of `getCheckedRadioButton`:

```
function getCheckedRadioButton() {
    return getRadioButtons().find(function (t) {
        return t.checked;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return call is referring to the callback of the `.forEach`. You never return the outer function, so your `x` is undefined. Though `.forEach` accepts a callback, it is synchronous, so you can fix it like this:

```
function getCheckedRadioButton() {
    var returnElement = false;
    getRadioButtons().forEach(function (t) {
        if (t.checked) {
            console.log(t);
            returnElement = t;
        }
    });
    return returnElement;
}
```

Note, you should handle the possibility of no match (which I set up here to return false. An empty object `{}` may also serve your purposes).

Comment: This will return the last checked radio button not the first.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir You are right, but that didn't seem out of line with the question to me. Not hard to fix if first is desired (add in a `if (!returnElement)` or something)